# Let X be a normed space. If the closed ball of radius r is compact (where r is not necessarily 1) then is X a finite dimensional space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We know that if the closed unit ball in this space is compact then X is of finite dimension. If I can prove that a closed ball of radius $r>0$ in X is compact, can it also be affirmed that X is of finite dimension? If so, can you tell me in which book I can find this result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes this is Riesz theorem. A normed space is locally compact iff it's of finite dimension.

Comment: You should be able to find this in almost any book about functional analysis.

Comment: In the functional analysis books I read they talk about the closed unit ball but not about a closed ball with radius r where r is not 1. So I wanted to know about a specific book.

Comment: Those are homeomorphic. Multiplication by a non-zero real number is a homeomorphism in any normed linear space.